# Unable to access second hdd. ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, root, permissions

This is the error i get when trying to write to my second hard drive.
 Error opening file '/media/hdd2/01 Queen - Keep Yourself Alive.mp3': Permission denied

The hdd is mounting on start up. but i have been unable to access it. It says the owner is root.

Please help i need this done before jan 10 I will be deploying to the middle east. and I despise windows. especially windows 8 which i have already gotten rid of.

Comment: Hey Paul, please type into a terminal the command 'cat /etc/fstab' and give us the output. (fstab is the file system table)

Comment: this is the output you requested.                                  UUID=c1a51310-b5a8-4148-94f4-933f0ea5d05e / ext4 defaults 0 1
UUID=0008-5234 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
UUID=048c0a6e-86cb-445d-b768-e62172fcbf05 swap swap sw 0 0

Comment: Got it. the answer was to log in to root.  

sudo bash.

then i had to use 

chown -R <username> <location>

After restart. it sill works, and i have sent files to it and deleted files. 

Sometimes a fresh start on the problem is all you need to fix it.

Thank you for your help Ben.